# Why is my female cat over-licking lower abdominal raw?

Tags: cats, behavior, grooming, anxiety, pregnancy

Mini Moose, my female cat, is pregnant and is over-licking her lower abdominal area raw. Two years ago she had a stillborn baby. Her babies are alive in her, I can feel them moving around.

[image]

Comment: Take her to a vet. Excessive licking can be a sign of pain.

Comment: Ok gotcha ,oh gosh ! I hope her babys are ok